# Galaxy S2 not showing progress with custom drawable

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with my app - most negative user reviews are coming from Galaxy S2 users and reporting that my progress bars don't work in the app. I've tested progress bars with most Android versions and I have no problems, it simply seems to be the case with Galaxy S2 (and possibly S3).

They are reporting that the progress bar stays gray.

The following is my drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270" />
</shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff1cb51c"
                android:endColor="#ff106b10"
                android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ffC71818"
            android:endColor="#ff821F1F"
            android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</clip></item></layer-list>
```

In a nutshell:

1. Background is gray
2. Regular progress color is red
3. Secondary progress is green.

I then have code that switches between showing regular or secondary progress in an arrayAdapter:

```
if (p.getBoughtGifts().size() == p.getGifts().size()) {
  progress.setMax(Math.round(p.getBudget()));
  progress.setProgress(0);
  progress.setSecondaryProgress(Math.round(p.getProgress()));
} else {
  progress.setMax(Math.round(p.getBudget()));
  progress.setProgress(Math.round(p.getProgress()));
  progress.setSecondaryProgress(0);
}
```

Can anyone think of anything that would cause issues with Galaxy S2/S3? Is this a bug in Touchwiz? Is there any way to emulate a Samsung Galaxy S2 device if I don't own an actual one?

Thanks in advance!